# ¿Por qué motivo un JFrame creado en un proyecto no muestra el contenido del diseño?

Tags: java, netbeans, apache-netbeans, netbeans-absolutelayout

Para este proyecto estoy utilizando el IDE `Apache NetBeans 17`, lo estoy haciendo en `Java con Ant` y en este creé un JFrame y unos días atrás lo pude diseñar y de igual forma dar actividades a los items del menú que tiene.

Mediante el IDE abrí nuevamente este JFrame para editar visualmente el contenido del mismo, pero envés de mostrarme los elementos usados (etiquetas, campos de texto, botones, etc.) me aparece en el medio de la misma un mensaje de que esta cargandose y luego de varios minutos no desaparece el mensaje y se muestra el contenido.

[image: ventana que no muestra el diseño]

En cambio si puedo visualizar el código (que es lo más importante) y de igual manera si puedo ejecutarlo (`Run File`) pero en el `Output` del proyecto el resultado que me indica es:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout.addLayoutComponent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1156)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JLayeredPane.addImpl(JLayeredPane.java:233)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JDesktopPane.addImpl(JDesktopPane.java:488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:440)
    at interfaces.SISconfig.usuariosActionPerformed(SISconfig.java:253)
    at interfaces.SISconfig$1.actionPerformed(SISconfig.java:75)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:374)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1028)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1072)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6626)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3389)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6391)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5001)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 28 seconds)
```

Por lo que no puedo ir a otra ventana interna para proceder a hacer las actividades que se encuentran en la JinternalFrame respectiva.

Ya modifiqué lo del AbsoluteLayout, es decir ya reemplacé la librería y puse `Clean and Build` pero de igual manera me sigue mostrando los mismos mensajes.

**Alguién tiene idea del motivo por lo que me está presentando estos problemas?**

***Actualización:***

Volví a descargarme el .jar de la librería, modifiqué el classpath y reinicie el IDE por si acaso, también revise y modifique la variable del sistema y cuando volví a abrir el IDE ya pude visualizar el diseño del JFrame.
Lo que persiste es el mensaje de compilación aunque si creo que se daño el archivo ya que cree uno nuevo con menos funciones y si funciona como lo deseo.

En la siguiente imagen se ve como está el administrador de librerías.

[image: Administrador general de librerías]

Comment: yo opino que se corrompió tu archivo .form, intenta usar el versionamiento o en su defecto el historial para regresarlo a una versión estable y corregir los problemas comparando

Answer (score 0):

Vamos a tratar de hacer funcionar el **AbsoluteLayout**, primero va a **"tools/Libraries"**, te fijas si en la lista de la izquierda, está el bendito **Layout**, si no está, le das al botón **Add JAR/Folder** seguidamente, buscas la ruta donde está instalado tu **NetBeans**, sigues navegando por la siguiente ruta: **"java/modules/ext"**, en esa carpeta, vas a encontrar el archivo **AbsoluteLayout.jar**, lo seleccionas y le das a **Add JAR/Folder**.
Ya sea que lo tenías, o lo agregaste, buscas en el navegador de proyectos, haces "click-derecho" en **Libraries**, y le das a **Add Library**, te lleva nuevamente a la lista de librerías, seleccionas **Absolute Layout** y le das a **Add Library**, esto debería solucionar el problema.