¿Por qué motivo no carga el diseño mi JInternalFrame?
Para este proyecto estoy usando el IDE Apache Netbeans 21, lo estoy haciendo en java con ant. Ya habia realizado el diseño de mi ventana, pero al volver a abrir mi proyecto más tarde me encuentro con que no carga el diseño de la ventana. Tengo otras JInternalFrame que tienen un diseño bastante similar y funcionan correctamente. Es importante aclarar que aún no le he agregado funcionalidad  a ninguna de las ventanas, sólamente diseño.


He corregido lasa etiquetas ya que parece ser un problema de matisse, yo pensaría que o tienes poca ram o que hubo un problema en renderizado, intenta pasar a la pestaña de código y regresar. PD: ¿Estás consciente que sin código no podremos reproducir tu problema?

Posiblemente relacionada con un problema en la librería AbsoluteLayout https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/596241/por-qu%c3%a9-motivo-un-jframe-creado-en-un-proyecto-no-muestra-el-contenido-del-dise
